# Submatrix extraction from matrix with loop tiling

Tags: c, loops, compiler-construction, transformation, tiling

I have the following matrix 4x4:

```
1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8

9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16
```

and I want extract and store (in some news variables) the four following submatrix 2x2:

```
[1 2

 5 6]

[3 4

 7 8]

[9 10

 13 14]

[11 12

 15 16]
```

It's like the "Rect" (http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Rect.html) function of openCV, but I don'want to use OpenCV.

I have to use a parallelizing compiler and so I would like to do the extraction of the submatrix with a famous loop transformation present in literature: "loop tiling" (also knows as "loop blocking" or "loop unroll and jam" or "loop stripmine and interchange"). - (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling)

Is it possible?

Comment: Loop tiling is only useful when you have many repetitions, since you can benefit from cache locality of the sub matrix. What do you plan doing with these tiles? See also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367246/loop-tiling-how-to-choose-block-size/20372396#20372396

Comment: I want to distribute those submatrices to other threads or device Cuda or others.

Comment: You don't need to *use* loop tiling for the extraction itself as you don't repeat the process, it's just one-time preparation

Comment: FYI: Rect is not a function. It is a data type, or basically speaking, a class. Also, it has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible?*

Of course …

```
    int n = 4;
    int matrix[4][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
    int submatrixes[n/2*n/2][2][2];
    int i, j, x, y, z;
    for (z = i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j += 2, ++z)
        for (x = 0; x < 2; x++)
          for (y = 0; y < 2; y++)
            submatrixes[z][x][y] = matrix[i+x][j+y];
```