# Can 2 small loops be faster than a big one?

Tags: performance, loops, cpu-cache

I was watching this video "how did we end up here?" by Martin Thompson of mechanical-sympathy.
(http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oxjT7veKi9c)

He claims that to make use of the L0 cache, sometimes it's better to have 2 small loops rather than a big one even though we might to to pass through the same list twice.

Is it possible? Anyway to create a trivial example code with measurement to demonstrate this?

Comment: Look up "loop tiling". Simple example here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367246/loop-tiling-how-to-choose-block-size/20372396#20372396

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
for (i = n; --i >= 0;){
  sum1 += a[i];
  sum2 += b[i];
}
```

as against:

```
double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
for (i = n; --i >= 0;){
  sum1 += a[i];
}
for (i = n; --i >= 0;){
  sum2 += b[i];
}
```

In the first example, the compiler has to generate code to "switch context" between indexing `a[i]` and `b[i]`, and keeping track of where the addition goes.
If `a` and `b` are complicated, the compiler may be unable to hold references to both of them in registers.
The result can be that this "context switching", because it has to be done on every iteration, takes more instruction cycles than the cost of the extra loop.
(With unrolling, it is even more true.)

This is still without considering cache issues.

Answer (score 0):

"Sometimes", maybe. If the loop's body may be split into parts without much overhead than the total count of executed instructions, either in two small loops or in one big loop, could be almost the same. And data cache helps anyway when traversing the input twice.

Yet I doubt if this trick could be really useful in general.